# Send Email with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a Form with From/Tp Input field and TextArea as Box. I want to send Email using Spring Boot. How can i send Email Using Spring Boot?

Thanks for Answers.

Comment: Advance thanks won't help brother. Show your code that you have tried and we can help on errors

Comment: Have you checked this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine now

That is my Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sendmail")
public class MailController {
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private String sendMail(HttpServletRequest request) {
         String covere = request.getParameter("covere");

        try {
            mailService.sendMail(covere);
            return "apply";
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "apply";
    }
}
```

That is my Service

```
@Component
public class MailService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendMail(String covere) throws MailException{

        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mail.setTo("yottiallipierre@gmail.com");
        mail.setFrom("yottiallipierre@gmail.com");
        mail.setSubject("Test");
        mail.setText(covere);
        javaMailSender.send(mail);
    }

}
```

That is my property Files

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port= 465
spring.mail.username = yottiallipierre@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = losangeles4004*
send.from.email= yottiallipierre@gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true;
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.fallback=false
```